Matlab simulation of PCB IFA
I am designing a PCB IFA and to get used to simulating it later down the road, I decided to first simulate an existing, known working design.
Known design for 0.062" Substrate (page 3)
This is the design I used. In Matlab I drew it up, with a tolerance of 0.1 mm.


For layer settings, I used these 2 setups.
Setup 1:

Layer 1 = Air, Er = 1, Thickness = 1 mm
Layer 2 = Silicon, Er = 11.7, Thickness = 2 mm
Layer 3 = Metallayer 1
Layer 4 = FR4, Er = 4.4, Thickness = 1.5 mm
Layer 5 = Metallayer 2
Layer 6 = Silicon, Er = 11.7, Thickness = 2 mm
Layer 7 = Air, Er = 1, Thickness = 1 mm

Setup 2:

Layer 1 = Air, Er = 1, Thickness = 1 mm
Layer 2 = Metallayer 1
Layer 3 = FR4, Er = 4.4, Thickness = 1.5 mm
Layer 4 = Metallayer 2
Layer 5 = Air, Er = 1, Thickness = 1 mm

Now onto the results: When I ran it first with setup 1, the following result came out of it:

Seems pretty okay, center is around 2.5 GHz, so antenna design seems to simulate okay.
Then I ran it with setup 2, just removing the silicon:

Suddenly, the existing, known to be working IFA design, just goes towards 3.5 GHz.
I expected after the run of setup 1, to have a similar graph, but with the center around 2.4 GHz more, instead of 2.5 GHz. But this surprised me a lot and have no idea what could be wrong. I didn't change any other settings, ran analysis settings on the auto default.
Some more info:

Feed diamater = 0.2 mm with feedtype being strip
Viadiameter = 0.2 mm
Center frequency = 2.4 GHz
Frequency range: 2:0.1:3.5 GHz (run from 2 GHz to 3.5 GHz with 0.1 GHz intervals)
Overlay on/off has no influence on results

If anyone has ideas/suggestions/questions, please advise. I am new to embedded PCB antenna design and information online seems to be very limited.

The y axis of these graphs appears to be multiplied by 10e-3 and is in dB. Therefore, it basically is equivalent to being 0 dB across the entire bandwidth, which is pure reflection, so neither of these graphs appear to be operating as expected even if the minima of the graph is where you expect it should be. In industry it is common to use -10 dB as the threshold for operating S11 for an antenna.
Common issues that would produce a result like this are the feed not actually being connected, or the ground and radiating element being shorted.

I just noticed the 10e-3 just now too, but still weird, as this is an IFA antenna where feed and GND are supposed to be shorted and it is an existing validated recomended design. Is matlab just not able to properly simulate IFA?

MATLAB has PIFA and inverted F antennas along with a number of other common microstrip patch antennas built in so I find it very unlikely it could not handle this geometry as it is a very common design. I would put my money on the issue being with the way it is being fed. How do you have the feed connected?

As visible in the first picture, the feeding point is at the start of the antenna, bot nut on the start of the feeding line coming from a "microcontroller" or whatever. Will try moving the feeding point and see what happens. As far as I read online, the feeding point needs to be < width of strip/2. No other requirements as far as I could see.

What about the vias? Any chance they're not actually shorted all the way through?

Double checked, they are all starting on metal layer 1 and ending on metal layer 2

Unfortunately I do all my antenna simulation design in FEKO and CST, so I don't have any MATLAB specific troubleshooting advice. Hopefully someone more familiar with the MATLAB sims can assist.
As a last tidbit, perhaps you could do a surface current visualization and compare with the datasheet to see if anything funky is occurring. Best of luck
